# How to host multiple websites in same Linode server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, nginx-config, linode

I have a Linode server where I host one website.

Now I want to configure one more website in same Linode server. Is it possible? What configuration shall I change?

I am trying to host Ruby websites. One is working fine, its path is `/root/apps/my_project_name/current/public`.

This is the place all my project file exists. When I try to configure second website, now I have the website in `/root/apps/my_2nd project`(all folders and files are here).

What shall I change in Nginx file?

This is my file:

```
  upstream puma_my_project_name_production {   server unix:/root/apps/my_project_name/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0; }

server {   listen 80;   server_name _;   root /root/apps/my_project_name/current/public;   try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_maxguard_production;

  client_max_body_size 4G;   keepalive_timeout 10;   error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;   error_page 503 @503;

  location @puma_my_project_name_production {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_pass http://puma_my_project_name_production;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /root/apps/my_project_name/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /root/apps/my_project_name/shared/log/nginx.error.log;   }   location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;   }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;   }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;   }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;   }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;   }
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: thanks let me check it

Answer (score 1):

I would give few suggestions:
1) use nginx+passenger (if not already, optional)
2) create separate "server" records in nginx conf and put right domain names
3) restart nginx